# Merge files with number of instances of words into new file with total number of instances of said words

Tags: unix, text, merge, terminal, concatenation

So I've got a lot of data (.txt files) on the following format:

```
  1500 this
  1450 is
  1200 some
  1000 data
```

The number is the number of instances of the following word in some other text files I concatenated with the following Unix terminal command:

```
  cat *.txt | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -gr > somefile.txt
```

Now I've got a number of somefile.txt (all with unique names; 135.txt - 143.txt). What I want to do is to merge these files into one big file while retaining and adding the number of word instances to a total number. So if it were two files with the following data:

```
  1500 this            1000 is
  1450 is      and     900  this
  1200 some            800  some
  1000 data            700  else
```

The new file should have the following data:

```
  2450 is
  2400 this
  2000 some
  1000 data
  700  else
```

What is a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END {for (i in a) {print a[i],i}}' file1 file2 file3 ... | sort -rn
```

Example output:

```
$ cat f1
1500 this
1450 is
1200 some
1000 data

$ cat f2
1000 is
900 this
800 some
700 else

$ awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END {for (i in a) {print a[i],i}}' f1 f2 | sort -rn
2450 is
2400 this
2000 some
1000 data
700 else
```

Explanation - this first loops through all the files, for each line it will add the value of the first column to the array index of the second column. After all files have been processed, the resulting array is output.

Comment: Thanks! A good solution and an explanation. It seems to work well besides that it can't handle the special characters in my native language. Do you have any idea how that could be fixed?